# Set column names from callback Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a Data table which shows so aggregate result from the core table (df). For that I am using Pandas, Dash and Plotly as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash_html_components import Div
from dash_table import DataTable
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

df = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2021-01-31', 'category_1', 20],
                   ['1', '2021-01-31', 'category_3', 12],
                   ['1', '2021-02-28', 'category_1', 35],
                   ['1', '2021-02-28', 'category_2', 17],
                   ['1', '2021-02-28', 'category_3', 35],
                   ['1','2021-03-31', 'category_1', 12],
                   ['1','2021-03-31', 'category_2', 58],
                   ['1','2021-03-31', 'category_3', 23],
                   ['2', '2021-01-31', 'category_1', 29],
                   ['2', '2021-01-31', 'category_2', 66],
                   ['2', '2021-01-31', 'category_3', 22],
                   ['2', '2021-02-28', 'category_1', 53],
                   ['2', '2021-02-28', 'category_2', 71],
                   ['2', '2021-02-28', 'category_3', 32],
                   ['2','2021-03-31', 'category_1', 19],
                   ['2','2021-03-31', 'category_2', 2],
                   ['2','2021-03-31', 'category_3', 99],
                   ['3', '2021-02-28', 'category_1', 53],
                   ['3', '2021-02-28', 'category_2', 71],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_1', 19],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_2', 2],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_3', 99],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_4', 39]],
                   columns=['Account', 'Date', 'category', 'Amount'])


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
                        dcc.Input(id="account", type="string", placeholder="Enter Account"),
                        DataTable(id='figure_1',
                        style_cell_conditional=[{'if': {'column_id': c}, 'textAlign': 'center'} for c in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
                        style_as_list_view=True,
                        fill_width=True,
                        style_cell={'font-size': '12px'},
                        style_header={'display': 'none'},
                        style_table={'height': '395px', 'overflowY': 'auto'})])
                                       

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('figure_1',  'data'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('account', 'value')])

def update_figura_2(account):
    df_query = df[df['Account'] == account].copy()
    df_query = df_query.groupby(['Account', 'Date', 'category']).agg({'Amount': 'sum'}).reset_index().pivot(values='Amount', columns='Date')
    df_query.index =  df.loc[df['Account'] == account, 'category'].copy()
    df_query.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return df_query.to_dict(orient='records')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

So the output i'd like to get:
[image]

However, when I run the code I get an empty Dataframe:
[image]

I suspect it has to be something with the callback, but I don't know what!

Should I define the columns parameter in the DataTable? If so, how could I get the columns of the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround where you don't have to build a table through it's html components manually as Derek's answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash_html_components import Div
from dash_table import DataTable
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

df = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2021-01-31', 'category_1', 20],
                   ['1', '2021-01-31', 'category_3', 12],
                   ['1', '2021-02-28', 'category_1', 35],
                   ['1', '2021-02-28', 'category_2', 17],
                   ['1', '2021-02-28', 'category_3', 35],
                   ['1','2021-03-31', 'category_1', 12],
                   ['1','2021-03-31', 'category_2', 58],
                   ['1','2021-03-31', 'category_3', 23],
                   ['2', '2021-01-31', 'category_1', 29],
                   ['2', '2021-01-31', 'category_2', 66],
                   ['2', '2021-01-31', 'category_3', 22],
                   ['2', '2021-02-28', 'category_1', 53],
                   ['2', '2021-02-28', 'category_2', 71],
                   ['2', '2021-02-28', 'category_3', 32],
                   ['2','2021-03-31', 'category_1', 19],
                   ['2','2021-03-31', 'category_2', 2],
                   ['2','2021-03-31', 'category_3', 99],
                   ['3', '2021-02-28', 'category_1', 53],
                   ['3', '2021-02-28', 'category_2', 71],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_1', 19],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_2', 2],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_3', 99],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_4', 39]],
                   columns=['Account', 'Date', 'category', 'Amount'])


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
                        dcc.Input(id="account", type="string", placeholder="Enter Account"),
                        html.Div(id='figure_1')
])

@app.callback(Output('figure_1', 'children'),
             [Input('account', 'value')])
def update_figura_2(account):
    df_query = df[df['Account'] == account].copy()
    df_query = df_query.groupby(['Account', 'Date', 'category']).agg({'Amount': 'sum'}).reset_index().pivot(values='Amount', columns='Date')
    df_query.index =  df.loc[df['Account'] == account, 'category'].copy()
    df_query.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return [DataTable(columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_query.columns],
                      data=df_query.to_dict('records'),                     
                      style_as_list_view=True,
                      fill_width=True,
                      style_cell={'font-size': '12px'},
                      style_header={'display': 'none'},
                      style_table={'height': '395px', 'overflowY': 'auto'})]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

The logic in this is to create the DataTable figure inside the callback and returning it as a figure's child, so the returned figure will be filtered by account with the columns/values you needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable) for the `DataTable` object, there are arguments for the `columns` and `data` but I could not successfully modify both of these attributes using a callback (if I figure this out, I will edit my answer).

I tried using the following callback to modify both the columns and data of the DataTable object:

```
@app.callback([Output('datatable', 'columns'), Output('datatable', 'data')],
    [Input('account', 'value')])
def update_table(account):
...
return df_query
```

... but I wasn't able to get this to work: even though no errors are thrown, the table won't display. My guess is that `columns` cannot be modified once the `DataTable` object is created, and this is why the callback fails to work as intended.

Instead, we can build the table from scratch using [a previous answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65656053/plotly-dash-how-to-filter-dashboard-with-multiple-dataframe-columns/65657694#65657694) as a template, wrapping the entire table in a `html.Div` container.

Since the DataFrame `df_query` resulting from each user input are indexed by category, we need to be careful about how we construct our table using `html.Tr` and `html.Th` objects from the dash_html_components library. We can iterate through each row of the DataFrame, adding the index value, followed by the remaining values of the row.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash_html_components import Div
import dash_table_experiments as dt
from dash_table import DataTable
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

df = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2021-01-31', 'category_1', 20],
                   ['1', '2021-01-31', 'category_3', 12],
                   ['1', '2021-02-28', 'category_1', 35],
                   ['1', '2021-02-28', 'category_2', 17],
                   ['1', '2021-02-28', 'category_3', 35],
                   ['1','2021-03-31', 'category_1', 12],
                   ['1','2021-03-31', 'category_2', 58],
                   ['1','2021-03-31', 'category_3', 23],
                   ['2', '2021-01-31', 'category_1', 29],
                   ['2', '2021-01-31', 'category_2', 66],
                   ['2', '2021-01-31', 'category_3', 22],
                   ['2', '2021-02-28', 'category_1', 53],
                   ['2', '2021-02-28', 'category_2', 71],
                   ['2', '2021-02-28', 'category_3', 32],
                   ['2','2021-03-31', 'category_1', 19],
                   ['2','2021-03-31', 'category_2', 2],
                   ['2','2021-03-31', 'category_3', 99],
                   ['3', '2021-02-28', 'category_1', 53],
                   ['3', '2021-02-28', 'category_2', 71],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_1', 19],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_2', 2],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_3', 99],
                   ['3','2021-03-31', 'category_4', 39]],
                   columns=['Account', 'Date', 'category', 'Amount'])

## construct a table with variable number of columns
def generate_table(df, max_rows=100):
    return html.Table(
        # Header
        [html.Tr([html.Th(df.columns.name)] + [html.Th(col) for col in df.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([html.Th(df.index.name)])] + 
        [html.Tr([html.Td(df.index[i])] + [ 
            html.Td(df.iloc[i][col]) for col in df.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(df), max_rows))]
    )

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
    dcc.Input(id="account", type="text", placeholder="Enter Account"),
    html.Div(id='table-container')
    ])                   

@app.callback(Output('table-container', 'children'),
    [Input('account', 'value')])
def update_table(account):
    df_query = df[df['Account'] == account].copy()
    df_query = df_query.groupby(['Account', 'Date', 'category']).agg({'Amount': 'sum'}).reset_index().pivot(values='Amount', columns='Date')
    df_query.index =  df.loc[df['Account'] == account, 'category'].copy()
    df_query.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    # print(df_query.to_dict(orient='records'))
    return generate_table(df_query)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

To make the table look a bit nicer, you can use some css to alternate row colors. In the same directory that you are running your dash app python file from, create a folder called `assets` and create a new file called `style.css` with the following contents:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!!! I'll mark this as the correct answer

Comment: Thanks @Snedecor, glad to hear it was helpful!